# column range of values depends on another column

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I am designing a small database containing a table that has a column whose range of possible values depends on another column's value (within the same table), ie.

### Table A

field_a (fk)

field_b (fk)

The range of values field_b can assume is dependent upon the value contained in field_b.

My solution was to combine field_a and field_b together in Table A and create an intermediate table with the following:

### Table A

field_ab (fk to Table B row)

### Table B

field_a (fk)

field_b (fk)

This way the fk in field_ab of Table A can only point to valid combinations of field_a and field_b, (assuming Table B has been correctly populated.)

This seems really awkward, especially for queries on field_a or field_b, so I know I am doing something fundamentally wrong - probably something to do with normal forms?

Could somebody please suggest the correct approach to my problem?

Comment: isn't a trigger a viable approach to 'setting a default' post-create, like a calculated attribute?

Comment: Is it practical to determine valid values of `field_b` for each and every possible `field_a` **in advance**?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an INSERT trigger to update the calculated value.

Comment: The RANGE field_b's value can assume is dependent upon the value of field_a, ie not the actual value of field_b. This means that a trigger would not be able to calculate the value.